# How can I show what a discount factor is a function of in a bargaining model?

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, discount-rate, bargaining

I was reading [Espinosa and Rhee (1989)](https://academic.oup.com/qje/article-abstract/104/3/565/1862865) and I was wondering how can the impact of exogenous changes on the discount factor can be shown mathematically. For example, if $A$ represents some exogenous variable that has a positive relationship with the patience of the firm (where $A$ can be later defined itself to be a function of things like technological progress), then can the discount factor be simply modelled as a function of $A$ and other components that can be kept constant?

I cannot find any text where the determinants of a discount factor are explicitly defined. Will a simple statement like: $\delta = \beta * A + \epsilon$ where $\beta$ represents the sensitivity of the discount factor to a change in $A$ work?

If this question shows a fundamental misunderstanding or lack of understanding in something essential to the topic, please share a reference I can use to understand this.

Thank you!